# Figure labels with custom captions

Tags: cross-referencing

Currently I am writing a paper for a specific journal which however has a unique style thus causing some malfunctions in LaTex. Let me be more specific. The following is the first figure of the paper.

```
\begin{figure}[!tH]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\hsize]{fig1.eps}
\captionb{1}{This is a test caption.}
\label{test}
\end{figure}
```

As we can see, the caption is modified and it is not the usual `\caption{}` but `\captionb{#}{}` instead, where # is the number of the figure (I admit this is not very clever).

Now when I write inside the text Fig. `\ref{test}` I get Fig. with empty space where the number 1 should be. I guess that this is because of the modification of the caption command.

A MWE can be found here: [MWE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/7pgi65cmugfutcq/MWE.rar)

#### `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{baltlat6}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{natbib}
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage[dvipdfm=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle = The title of my PDF, pdfauthor = My name, pdfsubject= The subject, pdfkeywords = keyword1 keyword2 keyword3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue, anchorcolor = red, citecolor = blue, filecolor = red, pagecolor = red, urlcolor = blue}

\begin{document}
\ \
\vspace{0.5mm}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\vspace{8mm}

\titlehead{Baltic Astronomy, vol.\,00, 0--000, 2014}

\titleb{TITLE}

\begin{authorl}
\authorb{Author}{}
\end{authorl}

\begin{addressl}
\addressb{}{Affiliation}
\end{addressl}

\submitb{Received: - ; accepted: -}

\begin{summary}
Abstarct
\end{summary}

\begin{keywords}
keywords
\end{keywords}

\resthead{title}
{author}

\sectionb{1}{INTRODUCTION}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\hsize]{example-image}
\captionb{1}{This is a test caption.}
\label{tst}
\end{figure}

As we can see in Fig. \ref{tst} there is ...

\end{document}
```

#### [`baltlat6.sty`](http://www.tfai.vu.lt/balticastronomy/files):

```
% Baltic Astronomy Document Style BALTLAT6.STY  (updated 2007 Dec 05).

\font\norma=cmr10
\font\normbf=cmbx10
\font\smallbf=cmbx9
\font\smalit=cmti9
\font\itl=cmti9
\def\em{\it}
\def\norm{\normalsize}
%SOME LITHUANIAN LETTERS
\def\ac{a\kern-.35em\accent'30\kern-.05em}
\def\Ac{A\kern-.35em\accent'30\kern-.05em}
\def\uc{u\kern-.35em\accent'30\kern-.05em}
\def\Uc{U\kern-.35em\accent'30\kern-.05em}
\def\msf{\footnotesize}


%\@options
\lineskip 1pt
\normallineskip 1pt
\def\baselinestretch{1}
\parskip 1pt
\textwidth=125mm
\textheight=190mm
%\oddsidemargin=25.4mm
%\evensidemargin=9.78mm
\oddsidemargin=2.2mm % at twoside, but for the same position of text
\evensidemargin=2.2mm % at twoside, but for the same position of text
\baselineskip=11pt



\def\titlehead#1{\vskip-15mm{\noindent\it #1\norm}
\vskip15mm
\thispagestyle{empty}}

\def\fpagehead#1{
\thispagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{\it Baltic Astronomy, vol.#1.}
\markboth{\it Baltic Astronomy, vol.#1.}
{\it Baltic Astronomy, vol.#1.}
\norm}


\def\resthead#1#2{
\pagestyle{amyheadings}
\markright{\it #1}
\markboth{\it #2}{\it #1}
\norm}
\def\runninghead{\resthead}



\marginparwidth 2cm
\marginparsep 10pt
\topmargin 22.17pt

\headheight 12pt
\headsep 25pt

\advance\textheight by \topskip
\columnsep 10pt
\columnseprule 0pt
\footnotesep 8.4pt

\skip\footins 10.8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt
\floatsep 12pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\textfloatsep 10pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\intextsep 10pt plus 4pt minus 4pt


\def\captionb#1#2{\small\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt\hhuad{\bf Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2} \baselineskip=11pt}

\def\captionr#1#2{\small\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt{\bf Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2} \baselineskip=11pt}

\def\captionc#1#2{\small\begin{center}\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt{\bf Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2}\end{center}\baselineskip=11pt}


\leftmargini 2.5em
\leftmarginii 2.2em
\leftmarginiii 1.87em
\leftmarginiv 1.7em
\leftmarginv 1em
\leftmarginvi 1em



\def\titleb#1{\noindent\hskip-.1pt{\parbox{123mm}{\bf #1}}\vspace{11mm}\norm}

\def\authorb#1#2{  #1$^{#2}$}
\def\addressb#1#2{\noindent{  $^{#1}$\,}
      \vtop{\hsize120mm\it\noindent\baselineskip10pt #2}\vskip.3mm\norm}


\def\authorl{\noindent\hskip.1pt}
\def\endauthorl{\vskip1mm\par\norm}

\def\addressl{\noindent\vskip.1pt}
\def\endaddressl{\vskip5mm\par\norm}

\def\submitb#1{\vskip2mm \noindent #1\vskip8mm}

\def\thanks#1{\vspace{4mm} ACKNOWLEDGMENTS.\ \ #1\par}

\def\sectionb#1#2{\vspace{5mm}\hbox{\kern-.9pt
{#1.\ \ }\vtop{\noindent #2}\nopagebreak}
\vspace{1mm} \noindent\baselineskip=11pt}

\def\subsectionb#1#2{\vspace{3mm}\hbox{\kern-.9pt
{\it #1.\ \ }\vtop{\noindent\it #2}\nopagebreak}
\vspace{.5mm} \noindent\baselineskip=11pt}

\def\subsubsectionb#1#2{\vspace{3mm}\hbox{\kern-.9pt
{#1.\ \ }\vtop{\noindent #2}\nopagebreak}
\vspace{.5mm} \noindent\baselineskip=11pt}


\def\summary{\vskip-5pt\noindent
\rightskip=0pc\leftskip=1pc%\parindent=\z@
 \baselineskip 10pt
{\bf Abstract.\ }}
\def\endsummary{\par\norm}


\def\keywords{\vskip 5pt\noindent
\rightskip=0pc\leftskip=1pc%\parindent=\z@
 \baselineskip 10pt
{\bf Key words:\ }}
\def\endkeywords{\par\norm}



% REFERENCES
%
\def\References{\vskip4mm
{\noindent
  REFERENCES\hfill}
  \vskip1mm

\norm}
\def\refb{\baselineskip=10pt
\vskip.3mm
\hangindent12pt\hangafter=1
\noindent\ignorespaces}
\def\endrefb{\endgroup}
%


\def\ps@myheadings{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
\def\@oddhead{\hbox{}\it\rightmark \hfil\norm}
\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenhead{\it\leftmark\hbox {}\hfil\norm}
\def\@evenfoot{}\def\sectionmark##1{}\def\subsectionmark##1{}}

\def\ps@amyheadings{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
\def\@oddhead{\hbox{}\it\rightmark \hfil\norma \thepage\norm}
\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\leftmark\hbox {}}
\def\@evenfoot{}\def\sectionmark##1{}\def\subsectionmark##1{}}

%TABLE TOOLS
\def\tablerule{\noalign{\vskip.7ex}\noalign{\hrule}\noalign{\vskip.5ex}}
\def\hhuad{\vrule height0pt depth0pt width10pt}%3.5mm
\def\huad{\vrule height0pt depth0pt width5pt}  %1.75mm
\def\sadd{\vrule height0pt depth0pt width.2em}
\def\badd{\vrule height0pt depth0pt width2em}
\def\add{\vrule height0pt depth0pt width.5em}
\def\addu{\vrule height0pt depth0pt width1.3em}
\def\addXcm{\vrule height0pt depth0pt width10truecm}
\def\qua{\vrule height0pt depth0pt width2pt}
\def\lhstrut{\vrule height10pt depth7pt width0pt}
\def\hstrut{\vrule height10pt depth0pt width0pt}
\def\lstrut{\vrule height0pt depth6pt width0pt}   %all of them
\def\llstrut{\vrule height1pt depth10pt width0pt} %not visible
\def\sstrut{\vrule height10pt depth5pt width0pt}
\def\hhstrut{\vrule height18pt depth0pt width0pt}
\def\lls{\vrule height0pt depth8pt width0pt}
\def\ddown{\lower2.5ex\hbox}
\def\ddow{\lower1.7ex\hbox}
\def\down{\lower1ex\hbox}
\def\uppp{\raise1ex\hbox}
\def\dnnn{\lower1ex\hbox}
\def\uuppp{\raise2ex\hbox}
\def\vm{\vskip3mm}
\def\hd{\hskip9.5mm}
\def\hs{\hskip2mm}
\def\hm{\hskip4mm}
\def\hll{\hd&\hfil\hd}
\def\hlm{\hm&\hfil\hm}
% ASTRONOMICAL ABBREVIATIONS
%
\def\sun{\hbox{$\odot$}}
\def\sq{\hbox{\rlap{$\sqcap$}$\sqcup$}}
\def\degr{\hbox{$^\circ$}}
\def\dgr{$^\circ\!$}
\def\arcmin{\hbox{$^\prime$}}
\def\arcsec{\hbox{$^{\prime\prime}$}}
\def\fd{\hbox{$.\!^{\rm d}$}}
\def\fh{\hbox{$.\!^{\rm h}$}}
\def\fm{\hbox{$.\!^{\rm m}$}}
\def\fs{\hbox{$.\!^{\rm s}$}}
\def\fdg{\hbox{$.\!^\circ$}}
\def\farcm{\hbox{$.\mkern-4mu^\prime$}}
\def\farcs{\hbox{$.\!\!^{\prime\prime}$}}
\def\fp{\hbox{$.\!\!^{\scriptscriptstyle\rm p}$}}

%\def~{\penalty100\thinspace}
\def\ts{\thinspace}
\def\oc{ $O\!-\!C$ }
\def\gmode{$g$-mode}
\def\pmode{$p$-mode}
\def\gmodes{$g$-modes}
\def\pmodes{$p$-modes}
\def\etal{et al.} %ApJlikes it this way now
\def\msun{$\,M_{\odot}$}
\def\rsun{$\,R_{\odot}$}
\def\lsun{$\,L_{\odot}$}
\def\te{$T_{\rm e}\,$}
\def\Te{$T_{\rm e}\,$}
\def\mstr{$\,M_{\star}$}
\def\rstr{$\,R_{\star}$}
\def\lstr{$\,L_{\star}$}
\def\angstr{\small A\kern-.57em\raise1.8ex\hbox{${\scriptscriptstyle\circ}$}$\,$}
\def\Pdot{$\dot P$}
\def\Tdot{$\dot T$}
\def\Rdot{$\dot R$}
\def\Tmax{$T_{\rm max}$}
\def\mitstar{$M\!$\raisebox{-.4ex}{$\star$}}
\def\mstar#1{$10^{-{#1}} {\rm M}_{\star}$}
\def\mh{${\rm M}_{\rm H}$}
\def\mhe{${\rm M_{\rm He}}$}
%the same definitions for using them in the math
\def\msunm{\,M_{\odot}}
\def\rsunm{\,R_{\odot}}
\def\lsunm{\,L_{\odot}}
\def\teff{T_{\rm eff}}
\def\Teff{T_{\rm eff}}
\def\mstrm{\,M_{\star}}
\def\rstrm{\,R_{\star}}
\def\lstrm{\,L_{\star}}
\def\Pdotm{\dot P}
\def\Tdotm{\dot T}
\def\Rdotm{\dot R}
\def\Tmaxm{T_{\rm max}}
\def\mstarm#1{10^{-{#1}} {\rm M}_{\star}}
\def\mhm{{\rm M}_{\rm H}}
\def\mhem{{\rm M_{\rm He}}}
%\chardef\o="1C
%\chardef\O="1F

%\ps@plain
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onecolumn
```

So, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How about providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that the community can play with? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. It is important that we see (and have a way to access) the document class. Regardless, if this is for a scientific journal paper, what do *they* recommend you do in this instance?

Comment: @Werner Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my post providing a link with a MWE.

Comment: Apart from the caption definition (about which no one can comment unless you show the definition) unless the float mechanism has been extensively redefined as well `[!tH]` is not going to do anything very useful. (well it will do the same as `[!t]` which makes it quite likely the float goes to the end of the document as `p` is dis-allowed)

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z No please don't link to external archives, See the link that Werner gave and make a small self contained example within the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can this be done inside the question? Inserting a working .tex file plus the whole .cls file will make the post enormous and what about the .eps file? I think that providing a link anyone can download the full working package of files and play with it.

Comment: We don't need the eps file (you can replace `\includegraphics` by `\fbox{foo}` )  and we don't need the whole cls file just the part that redefines caption.   External links are discouraged as if you want help you should do the initial work in making a debuggable example, and this site is archived forever and unless you make the same commitment to the external link this question becomes less useful in the future. Finally if you must use an archive (which is never the case) please don't use  a non standard format like rar use zip or tar or something.

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\captionb` is defined in your custom `baltlat6.sty` as

```
\def\captionb#1#2{\small\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt\hhuad{\bf Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2} \baselineskip=11pt}
```

so it is not designed for `\label`-`ref` mechanism.

Add the following lines in your preamble so to let those custom commands support it:

```
\makeatletter
\def\captionb#1#2{\refstepcounter\@captype\small\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt\hhuad{\bfseries Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2} \baselineskip=11pt}

\def\captionr#1#2{\refstepcounter\@captype\small\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt{\bfseries Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2} \baselineskip=11pt}

\def\captionc#1#2{\refstepcounter\@captype\small\begin{center}\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt{\bfseries Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2}\end{center}\baselineskip=11pt}
\makeatother
```

Your modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{baltlat6}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{natbib}
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage[dvipdfm=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle = The title of my PDF, pdfauthor = My name, pdfsubject= The subject, pdfkeywords = keyword1 keyword2 keyword3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue, anchorcolor = red, citecolor = blue, filecolor = red, pagecolor = red, urlcolor = blue}

\makeatletter
\def\captionb#1#2{\refstepcounter\@captype\small\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt\hhuad{\bfseries Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2} \baselineskip=11pt}

\def\captionr#1#2{\refstepcounter\@captype\small\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt{\bfseries Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2} \baselineskip=11pt}

\def\captionc#1#2{\refstepcounter\@captype\small\begin{center}\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt{\bfseries Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2}\end{center}\baselineskip=11pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ \
\vspace{0.5mm}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\vspace{8mm}

\titlehead{Baltic Astronomy, vol.\,00, 0--000, 2014}

\titleb{TITLE}

\begin{authorl}
\authorb{Author}{}
\end{authorl}

\begin{addressl}
\addressb{}{Affiliation}
\end{addressl}

\submitb{Received: - ; accepted: -}

\begin{summary}
Abstarct
\end{summary}

\begin{keywords}
keywords
\end{keywords}

\resthead{title}
{author}

\sectionb{1}{INTRODUCTION}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\hsize]{fig1.eps}
\captionb{1}{This is a test caption.}
\label{tst}
\end{figure}

As we can see in Fig. \ref{tst} there is ...


\end{document}
```

now yields:

[image]

---

### EDIT

Since also `\sectionb` & friends lack this functionality, I'll suggest you to also add the following lines in the preamble

```
\def\sectionb#1#2{\refstepcounter{section}\vspace{5mm}\hbox{\kern-.9pt
{#1.\ \ }\vtop{\noindent #2}\nopagebreak}
\vspace{1mm} \noindent\baselineskip=11pt}

\def\subsectionb#1#2{\refstepcounter{subsection}\vspace{3mm}\hbox{\kern-.9pt
{\it #1.\ \ }\vtop{\noindent\it #2}\nopagebreak}
\vspace{.5mm} \noindent\baselineskip=11pt}

\def\subsubsectionb#1#2{\refstepcounter{subsubsection}\vspace{3mm}\hbox{\kern-.9pt
{#1.\ \ }\vtop{\noindent #2}\nopagebreak}
\vspace{.5mm} \noindent\baselineskip=11pt}
```

---

### EDIT #2

Since `baltlat6.sty` does not define captions for tables, we can define three types, `\captiontb`, `\captiontr`, `\captiontc` corresponding to `\captionb`, `\captionr`, `\captionc` for figures, but to be used inside tables.

So, replace all the additional code mentioned above and put the following lines in your preamble:

```
\def\captionb#1#2{\refstepcounter{figure}\small\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt\hhuad{\bfseries Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2} \baselineskip=11pt}

\def\captionr#1#2{\refstepcounter{figure}\small\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt{\bfseries Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2} \baselineskip=11pt}

\def\captionc#1#2{\refstepcounter{figure}\small\begin{center}\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt{\bfseries Fig.\,#1.}
 \,#2}\end{center}\baselineskip=11pt}

\def\captiontb#1#2{\refstepcounter{table}\small\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt\hhuad{\bfseries Table\,#1.}
 \,#2} \baselineskip=11pt}

\def\captiontr#1#2{\refstepcounter{table}\small\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt{\bfseries Table\,#1.}
 \,#2} \baselineskip=11pt}

\def\captiontc#1#2{\refstepcounter{table}\small\begin{center}\vspace{2mm}
\vbox{\baselineskip=9.5pt{\bfseries Table\,#1.}
 \,#2}\end{center}\baselineskip=11pt}

\def\sectionb#1#2{\refstepcounter{section}\vspace{5mm}\hbox{\kern-.9pt
{#1.\ \ }\vtop{\noindent #2}\nopagebreak}
\vspace{1mm} \noindent\baselineskip=11pt}

\def\subsectionb#1#2{\refstepcounter{subsection}\vspace{3mm}\hbox{\kern-.9pt
{\it #1.\ \ }\vtop{\noindent\it #2}\nopagebreak}
\vspace{.5mm} \noindent\baselineskip=11pt}

\def\subsubsectionb#1#2{\refstepcounter{subsubsection}\vspace{3mm}\hbox{\kern-.9pt
{#1.\ \ }\vtop{\noindent #2}\nopagebreak}
\vspace{.5mm} \noindent\baselineskip=11pt}
```

Comment: Yes it is working like a charm! Many thanks for pointing also the issue of the Sections labels. BTW, what about Table labels?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z You're welcome. There's no captions defined for tables in the style file. Do you want me to define some?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z See the second edit.

Comment: Why there are always three types? I mean what's the difference between `\captionb` and `\captionr`? Is there a way to modify the `baltlat6.sty` file (creating a new version) instead of adding all these commands in the preamble?